# Grammatically of the word "meaning" in this context

Tags: word-meaning, grammaticality

I just saw a sentence:

> It is said that history repeats itself. **Meaning** what we did 600 years ago might repeat itself.

Here the word **meaning** has been used **at the beginning** of the sentence.

Is it grammatical?

> *Can I use* **that means** *instead of* **meaning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes and Yes

In this construction, the word "meaning" has exactly the same meaning as the two-word phrase "that means". It expands on and explains the previous text.

However, the quoted example using "meaning" is grammatical, and is a common and natural construction. There is no  grammatical reason to avoid it. The choice is purely one of style.

Comment: How about: "You can also use this word MEANING to work hard." Is the word "meaning" used as a PARTICIPIAL PHRASE in this example?

Comment: @user100323 that should be asked as a separate, but related question. I can't tell without more context, but I think "meaning" would be a gerund, or perhaps a present participle, in your suggested sentence. if you ask this as a new question, please provide as much context as possible.

Comment: @David Siegel It IS to do with style, but I think starting a sentence with 'Meaning' is colloquial: not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't *quite* grammatical. ***Meaning what we did 600 years ago might repeat itself*** is not a perfect sentence. It seems to need a main verb. For that reason **That means** is much better.

> That means what we did 600 years ago might repeat itself.

It would flow even better if you used a colon, or perhaps just a comma, before *meaning*, and said 'which means'.

> It is said that history repeats itself: which means what we did 600
>   years ago might repeat itself.

The fact that it states something blindingly self-evident makes it hard to improve!